# How to fit the windows size according to display resolution

Tags: python, pyqt

I have window size issue according to the display resolution.

- To dynamic control for window size, I set the size policy as **Preferred**

In case of 1280 X 1024 resolution, the auto adjusting window size function works well.
Low resolution such as 1280 X 800, the vertical window size is slightly larger than actual resolution.

But I found out the window size fit the display resolution, when i changed screen resolution in windows display configuration.

Could you share your comment or suggest resize the window according to display resolution ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you explain this? "I found out the window size fit the display resolution, when i changed screen resolution in windows display configuration."

Comment: I mean the app windows size can be adjusted automatically, when I adjusted the display resolution of desktop configuration page in Windows OS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Qt provides a [QScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) interface, which allows access to the "portion" of the visible desktop (theoretically) shown in each physical screen.

"Screens" can be retrieved from the QGuiApplication in various ways, so that we can have an interface to do various things:

- access to all [`screens()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screens), including the main one ([`primaryScreen()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#primaryScreen-prop);
- signals that notify whenever screens are [added](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screenAdded) or [removed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screenRemoved);
- [full](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#geometry-prop) and [available](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#availableGeometry-prop) geometries (the latter being the actual geometry excluding things like system menus or task bar), and various [change notifications](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#signals);

Considering the above, it's pretty easy to create a window that automatically adapts to screen changes.

In the following example, I've created a basic QWidget that adapts to the current main screen (or the cursor position) and accepts a scale ratio based on the screen size, and an aspect ratio that properly sets the size based on the screen.

```
class AutoResizeWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, scale=2/3, aspectRatio=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.scale = scale
        self.aspectRatio = aspectRatio

        font = self.font()
        font.setPointSize(font.pointSize() * 2)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.sizeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(font=font, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.resizeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Update to screen size')

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.sizeLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.resizeButton)

        self.updateScreens()
        self.updateSize()

        self.resizeButton.clicked.connect(self.updateSize)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().screenAdded.connect(self.updateScreens)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().screenRemoved.connect(self.updateSize)

    def updateScreens(self):
        for screen in QtWidgets.QApplication.screens():
            try:
                screen.availableGeometryChanged.connect(
                    self.updateSize, QtCore.Qt.UniqueConnection)
            except TypeError:
                # already connected
                pass

    def updateSize(self):
        if not self.isVisible():
            screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.screenAt(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        else:
            center = self.geometry().center()
            screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.screenAt(center)
            if not center in screen.geometry():
                screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.screenAt(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        screenGeo = screen.geometry()

        if self.aspectRatio:
            baseSize = QtCore.QSize(round(self.aspectRatio * 100), 100)
        else:
            baseSize = screenGeo.size()

        newSize = baseSize.scaled(screenGeo.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        newSize *= self.scale

        windowGeo = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), newSize)
        windowGeo.moveCenter(screenGeo.center())
        self.setGeometry(windowGeo)
        self.updateLabel()

    def updateLabel(self):
        screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.screenAt(self.geometry().center())
        screenIndex = QtWidgets.QApplication.screens().index(screen)
        screenSize = screen.size()
        self.sizeLabel.setText('''
            Screen {index} ("{name}")<br/>
            Size: {sw}x{sh} ({sr:.02f}:1)<br/><br/>
            Window size: {ww}x{wh} ({wr:.02f}:1)
        '''.format(
            index=screenIndex, 
            name = screen.name(), 
            sw = screenSize.width(), 
            sh = screenSize.height(), 
            sr = screenSize.width() / screenSize.height(), 
            ww = self.width(), 
            wh = self.height(), 
            wr = self.width() / self.height()
        ))

    def moveEvent(self, event):
        self.updateLabel()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateLabel()
```

Important notes:

- by default, Qt resizes top-level windows to 2/3 of the screen size (unless any content forces a bigger size); overriding `sizeHint()` is *not* enough, as Qt will always limit the size to 2/3 of the screen width or height;
- with the above code, switching screens can result in recursion problems, depending on the DPI scaling;
- depending on the OS and screen layout, the `geometry()` and `availableGeometry()` might not always correspond to the real value for extended ("virtual") desktops;
- this question is tagged for [pyqt](/questions/tagged/pyqt), which, unlike [pyside](/questions/tagged/pyside), implements "magic methods" for some classes; among these, it supports [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) for both QRect and QRectF, allowing the usage of `point in rect` (which actually calls `rect.contains(point)` internally); I believe that the PyQt syntax is better, smart and more pythonic, but, if you use PySide, you must use the full *Qt compliant* syntax, otherwise you'll get an exception (because `in` considers the target object as an iterator if `__contains__` is not defined):
  `if not screen.geometry().contains(center):`

Comment: "if not center in screen.geometry()" gets "QRect is not iterable" (PySide 6.4.0). This works, and might be what you intended: "if not screen.geometry().contains(center)".

Comment: @j77h Unlike PySide, PyQt implements some "magic methods" (also called "dunder", as in "double underscore", like `__init__`) that reflect basic Qt functions. Among these, it implements [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) for both QRect and QRectF which do what `rect.contains(point)` does: for PyQt, `point in rect` is the same as `rect.contains(point)`. Since the question is tagged for PyQt, I've used that implementation, as I believe it very intuitive (and *pythonic*), even if not completely compliant to the Qt API.