# Minimal PySide6 code to get screen resolution

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I'm fairly new to Qt for Python, and tried to get screen resolution like this:

```py
screen = QtGui.QScreen()
print(f'screen geometry: {screen.geometry()}')
```

The numbers it gave were crazy, and were different every time I ran the script.

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Searching the web gave me surprisingly little info about this.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70888194/3147828) provided the clues that I needed.

Seems like you have to get to a screen through `QApplication.screens()`, which returns a list of `QScreen` objects.

I wanted to know the **minimal** PySide6 code to get the resolution of a single screen ...

EDIT, UTC 22-11-13 15h :

Researching the suggestion in @musicamente's comment, I found [QGuiApplication.primaryScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtGui/QGuiApplication.html#PySide6.QtGui.PySide6.QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen).

For a single screen, or the main one, this two-liner gets the screen size in pixels:

```py
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
width,height = QGuiApplication().primaryScreen().size().toTuple()
```

Caution: beginner's error: `QGuiApplication.primaryScreen()` returns `None`,
as `QGuiApplication` does not make an *instance* without `()` after it.

In the original answer below, the code seems not quite so minimal now.

---

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

class App(QApplication):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        (width,height) = self.screens()[0].size().toTuple()
        print( width,height )

App()
```

`self.screens()[0]` returns the main (or only) QScreen object.

Note that you don't need to create any window or widget.
Although you need a `QApplication` instance, you do *not* need to run its `exec` loop.

If you want to recurse through all screens, you can add something like:

```py
for scrn in self.screens() :
    print(f'index : {self.screens().index(scrn)}')
    print(f'\n name       : {scrn.name()}')
    print('\n actual size')
    print(f'  width      : {scrn.size().width()}')
    print(f'  height     : {scrn.size().height()}')
    print('\n available size')
    print(f'  width      : {scrn.availableSize().width()}')
    print(f'  height     : {scrn.availableSize().height()}\n')
```

Comment: The concept is that anything required by a specific feature of a Q[...]Application, needs a Q[...]Application instance to be created first. Besides, you don't really need a subclass at all, as you can just use a reference (even a local one if you do not need a Qt application anymore): `print([screen.size() for screen in QGuiApplication([]).screens()])`